# How to use OpenCL to write directly to linux framebuffer with zero-copy?

Tags: opencl, framebuffer, memory-mapping, zero-copy

I am using OpenCL to do some image processing and want to use it to write RGBA image directly to framebuffer. Workflow is shown below:

1) map framebuffer to user space.

2) create OpenCL buffer using clCreateBuffer with flags of "CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR"

3) use clEnqueueMapBuffer to map the results to framebuffer.

However, it doesn't work. Nothing on the screen. Then I found that the mapped virtual address from framebuffer are not same as the virtual address mapped OpenCL. Has any body done a zero-copy move of data from GPU to framebuffer?Any help on what approach should I use for this?

Some key codes:

```
if ((fd_fb = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR, 0)) < 0) {
    printf("Unable to open /dev/fb0\n");
    return -1;
}
fb0 = (unsigned char *)mmap(0, fb0_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_fb, 0);
...
cmDevSrc4 = clCreateBuffer(cxGPUContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uchar) * imagesize * 4, NULL, &status);
...
fb0 = (unsigned char*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(cqCommandQueue, cmDevSrc4, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(cl_uchar) * imagesize * 4, 0, NULL, NULL, &ciErr);
```

Answer (score 1):

For zero-copy with an existing buffer you need to use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` flag in the `clCreateBuffer()` function call. In addition you need give the pointer to the existing buffer as second to last argument.

I don't know how linux framebuffer internally works but it is possible that even with the zero-copy from device to host it leads to extra copying the data to GPU for rendering. So you might want to render the OpenCL buffer directly with OpenGL. Check out `cl_khr_gl_sharing` extension for OpenCL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know OpenCL yet, I was just doing a search to find out about writing to the framebuffer from it and hit your post.  Opening it and mmapping it like in your code looks good.

I've done that with the CPU: https://sourceforge.net/projects/fbgrad/

That doesn't always work, it depends on the computer.  I'm on an old Dell Latitude D530 and not only can't I write to the framebuffer but there's no GPU, so no advantage to using OpenCL over using the CPU.  If you have a /dev/fb0 and you can get something on the screen with

```
cat /dev/random > /dev/fb0
```

Then you might have a chance from OpenCL.  With a Mali at least there's a way to pass a pointer from the CPU to the GPU.  You may need to add some offset (true on a Raspberry Pi I think).  And it could be double-buffered by Xorg, there are lots of reasons why it might not work.